# Best practices when dockerizing phpunit testing

Tags: php, docker, phpunit

I work on a PHP 7.4 project that already runs on Docker. Currently, my tests (PHPunit only) are in projects/tests and my source code inside projects/src. When the docker container is built, the src folder is taken to the /app folder and the rest of the project (docker config files and tests files) are discarded. I assume it is do so to lighten the container size.

First of all : Is that a common/good practice or should I put my tests inside the container ? Or maybe should I make another "testing" container with both my sources and my tests ?

In that second scenario, is there a way to inherit a whole docker file and just add some stuff inside (basically a second test container would be an almost identical container, but with the tests files copied and XDebug installed).

Also, there may be a third option i haven't considered.

I'm really new to docker and quite lost tbh.

Regards,

Comment: Questions like this that asks for "Best practices" are off-topic here since most answers will be opinion based.

Comment: Yeah, I can undestand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount the testing code on the container when you run it. Check out -v option for docker run. Next step would be to override the docker entrypoint or run a custom command that would run the tests.

If you need extra packages to run your tests, it would be wiser to inherit the initial image, install whatever you have to install and run the tests with that.